# Scale css animation every second without hover

Tags: html, css, animation, transform, transition

I want to scale this pricetag but i only know how to do it on hover. But i want to do it every 3 seconds without hover. I have tried so many ways with animations but it loose the 15 deg rotation

HTML:

```
<div class="tagContainer"><div class="priceTag"><div class="priceText">Rebajado<br>¡Hasta el<br>22/03!</div></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.tagContainer {
    margin:20px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.priceTag {
    background-color: #525199;
    width: 141px;
    height: 102px;
    clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 20%, 100% 100%, 20% 100%, 0% 70%, 0% 30%);
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 14px;
    transition: transform 300ms  ease-in-out;
    transform: rotate(15deg);
    
}

.priceTag:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1) rotate(15deg);
}

.priceTag:after {
    content: "";
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 15px;
    top: 45px;
}

.priceText {
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    align-self: center;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm really not an expert at this, but I took your code, put it in a JSFiddle, and added a bit of [code similar to what I found here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations). It seems to work:

https://jsfiddle.net/b3fze87w/1/

Press the "Run" button.

The trick is adding:

```
.priceTag {
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-name: zooming;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

to the priceTag and then make the keyframes like this:

```
@keyframes zooming {
  80% {
    transform: rotate(15deg);
  }
  90% {
     transform: scale(1.1) rotate(15deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(15deg);
  }
}
```

I'm sure this can be further optimized.

Comment: This is perfect!! Thank you so much :) Im gonna try to understand it! but it works perfectly

Comment: Do you know how to eliminate the shadow that appears on one side in the animation? regards

Comment: @Miguelbastidas: Sorry, I don't see a shadow.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question right, you must use `animation-iteration-count` property in here:

```
.priceTag {
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-name: zooming;
    background-color: #525199;
    width: 141px;
    height: 102px;
    clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 20%, 100% 100%, 20% 100%, 0% 70%, 0% 30%);
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 14px;
    transition: transform 300ms  ease-in-out;
    transform: rotate(15deg);

    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

Take a look at this https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-iteration-count.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.priceTag {
    background-color: #525199;
    width: 141px;
    height: 102px;
    clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 20%, 100% 100%, 20% 100%, 0% 70%, 0% 30%);
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 14px;
    transform: rotate(15deg);
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;

}

@keyframes example {
    from {
        background-color: #525199;
    }

    50% {
        transform: scale(1.1);
        background-color: #DB2955;
    }

    to {
        transform: scale(1) rotate(15deg);
        background-color: #525199;
    }
}
```